# Can Automapper ignore void methods?

Tags: automapper

I am new to Automapper, so I am not sure if this is possible.

I would like to map a class, but get it to ignore methods that are void. Below is an illustration of the code I have. When I run this I get the following exception message.

> An unhandled exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException'
>   occurred in AutoMapper.dll

Unfortunately it isn't an option to change the interface, so I assume if this is possible there is some sort of configuration I am missing?

```
public interface IThing
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void IgnoreMe();
}

public class Foo : IThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void IgnoreMe()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fooSource = new Foo {Name = "Bobby"};
        Mapper.CreateMap<IThing, IThing>();

        var fooDestination = Mapper.Map<IThing>(fooSource);
        Console.WriteLine(fooDestination.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `ConstructUsing` to specify which implementation Automapper should create: `Mapper.CreateMap<IThing, IThing>().ConstructUsing((ResolutionContext c) => new Foo());`

Comment: By the way you are using `IThing` as the destination type? Because `Mapper.CreateMap<IThing, Foo>();` would also work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using [an interface as a destination](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/) type AutoMapper will dynamically create an implementation (proxy) type for you.

However the **proxy generation only supports properties**, so it throws this not too descriptive exception for your `IgnoreMe` method. So you cannot ignore your `IgnoreMe` method.

As a workaround you can explicitly specify how the destination objects should be constructed with using one of the `ConstructUsing` overloads in this case AutoMapper does not generate proxies.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IThing, IThing>()
      .ConstructUsing((ResolutionContext c) => new Foo());
```

Or unless you have no good reason, you can directly map to `Foo`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IThing, Foo>();
```